# Syntax html in asp.net + vb.net

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

This my code

```
    Dim verifyUrl As String = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) & Page.ResolveUrl("~/verify.aspx?ID=" & sGUID)
    mail.Body = "<html>" & _
                "<head>" & _
                "<meta http-equiv=""Content-Language"" content=""fr"">" & _
                "<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=windows-1252"">" & _
                "</head>" & _
                "<body>" & _
                " <p>Hello, <%UserName%>. You are receiving this email because you recently created a new account at my" & _
                "site. Before you can login, however, you need to first visit the following link:</p>" & _
                "<p> //////Here put an href whit the value verifyUrl ///// </p>" & _
                "</body>" & _
                "</html>"
                mail.Body = mail.Body.Replace("<%VerifyUrl%>", verifyUrl)
                mail.Body = mail.Body.Replace("<%UserName%>", nom)


      Try for long time to put an like <a href"<%verifyUrl%>"</a> but this not work well................
```

Please help me to enter this simple html line!!!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What's the output when you do something like this? `<a href='<%VerifyUrl%>'>Click Here</a>`

Comment: Thank you so much this is work, it's not so easy to found the true syntax!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<a href='<%VerifyUrl%>'>Click Here</a>
```